# Get Values from views inflated in a PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe-gesture, android-pageradapter

I have an `Activity` with a `ViewPager` and  a custom adapter that implements the `PagerAdaper`. I am inflating a view inside the `PagerAdapter` and adding sub views to the parent view. These sub views are `RadioGroup`, `Checkboxes`, `EditText` etc. depending upon a certain parameter of the object of whose list I pass to the adapter.

I want to get the values from these sub views once the page is changed. But since my inflation code is in the adapter, I need to know how can I detect the page change from my adapter itself.

Here is my code for the adapter :-

```
 public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
        {
            var view = voteFormActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.active_votes_layout, container, false);
            txtvoteTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTitle);
            //radioGroup = view.FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.radioGroupChoice);
            btnSubmit = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSubmit);
            layoutForcomponents = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutForComponents);


            radioGroup = new RadioGroup(voteFormActivity);

            var data = selectedVotes.ElementAt(position);



            if (data != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Title))
                {
                    txtvoteTitle.Text = data.Title;
                }


                var choiceList = data.Choices;

                if (choiceList != null && choiceList.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (checkParam == "RadioChoice")
                    {
                        foreach (var choice in choiceList)
                        {
                            RadioButton rButton = new RadioButton(voteFormActivity);
                            rButton.Text = choice;
                            radioGroup.AddView(rButton);
                            layoutForcomponents.RemoveAllViews();
                            layoutForcomponents.AddView(radioGroup);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (checkParam == "CheckBoxChoice")
                    {
                        foreach (var choice in choiceList)
                        {
                            CheckBox cButton = new CheckBox(voteFormActivity);
                            cButton.Text = choice;
                            radioGroup.AddView(cButton);
                            layoutForcomponents.RemoveAllViews();

                            layoutForcomponents.AddView(radioGroup);

                        }
                    }

                }
                //if (checkParam == "MultiLineText")
                else{
                    EditText etMultilineText = new EditText(voteFormActivity);
                    etMultilineText.Hint = "Enter feedback";
                    etMultilineText.SetLines(6);
                    layoutForcomponents.RemoveAllViews();

                    layoutForcomponents.AddView(etMultilineText);
                }
            }
            container.AddView(view);
            return view;
        }
```

I pass the adapter to my ViewPager as follows:-

```
mViewPager.Adapter = new PollViewPagerAdapter(this, this.FragmentManager, AppHelper.SelectedVotes);
```

How can I detect the page change and get the values from the `RadioGroup`, `Checkbox` and `EditText` ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is an `ViewPager.onPageChangeListener ` which you attach to the viewpager. Is this what you were after? I can add it as an answer if so

Comment: @RobVoisey `ViewPager.onPageChangeListener` has to be applied to the Activity, but the values I need are inflated in the `PagerAdapter`, how can I get those values when the page changes?

Comment: Can you not simply store the views as fields on your class? `ViewPager.onPageChangeListener` lets you know when the page has been updated and you can get the page currently showing, then you'll know which view fields to use.

Comment: You can also add a `TextChangeListener` for the `EditText`; there are similar methods out there for radio group and CheckBoxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to know when a page is scrolled inside the adapter. You can assign a page scrolled listener to the pager like this:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(object : OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {}
    })
```

I'd keep the logic outside the adapter. You can make even an interface between your Activity/Fragment and your Adapter to listen to events like radiogroup state changes and stuff like that.

**Edit**

Let me try to elaborate further. There's no correct answer to your question. You can implement this sort of behavior in many ways. Let's suppose you've got a radiogroup in your adapter with a checked change listener. Inside the checked change method you can call some interface method you defined inside the adapter for example.

```
interface RadioChangedListener{
    fun radioChanged(radioId: Int)
}
```

Define this interface inside the adapter and make your fragment/activity implement it. Then declare the adapter passing it the activity/fragment in the constructor as a radioChangedListener object:

```
class YourAdapter(var listItems: MutableList<YourItem>, val yourListener: RadioChangedListener)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.YourHolder>() {

//...adapter code

}
```

Finally, in your radiogroup listener you can call your interface method like so (giving you the Java code for this cause I'm lazy):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        yourListener.radioChanged(checkedId)
    }
});
```

This will trigger your `radioChanged` method inside the activity, in which you can store your value.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am exactly looking for the second part of your answer. Can you please elaborate on how I can listen to events like radiogroup state changes  between the adapter and Activity?

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out

Comment: No problem, you could also store the values inside fields in your adapter and call a method like `getCurrentSelectedValues()` from the Activity inside the onPageChanged method, getting the values for the item in position-1